# How to delete web application cookies in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I am new in reactJs I want to delete cookies and login session on logout button to diconnnect user's session. 
But I unable to access cookies in the code.

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access cookies through `document.cookie`. In order to remove a cookie, you can set the expiration date to a date in the past:

```
document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
```

Solution is described in here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

There are also helper libraries to work with cookies (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie), but those will increase your bundle size slightly.

Comment: In my case cookies are not manually in the code.But it is added while logged in and respective sessionsid are added in the browser cookies and that I want delete.(I access want delete cookies which are generated during login)

Comment: So if you want to access cookies in JavaScript that were set by the server, make sure that the cookie flag `httpOnly ` is set to false. However, as this lowers the security of the web application, I would suggest you to remove the cookie on the server side. Example in express: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.clearCookie

Comment: And when you remove the cookie, make sure to also invalidate the session on the server.

Answer (score 11):

If you are setting the cookie on a response in a login route in express backend for JWT and are using 'httpOnly' option, you are unable to access the token from the client/react, even when using a third party library like 'universal-cookie' or 'document.cookie'.

You will need to clear the cookie on the response from the backend e.g. when a user logs out.

Front-end:

```
// React redux logout action
export const logout = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await axios.get('/api/auth/logout')
        localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')
        dispatch({ type: type.USER_LOGOUT })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Backend:

```
const User = require('../../models/userModel')
const generateToken = require('../../utils/generateToken')

// @desc    Auth user & get token
// @route   POST /api/auth/login
// @access  Public
const login = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (user && (await user.verifyPassword(password))) {
            let token = generateToken(user._id)
            res.cookie('token', token, {
                maxAge: 7200000, // 2 hours
                secure: false, // set to true if you're using https
                httpOnly: true,
            })
            res.json({
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
                token: token,
            })
        } else {
            res
                .status(401)
                .json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid email or password' })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.toString() })
    }
}

// @desc    Logout controller to clear cookie and token
// @route   GET /api/auth/logout
// @access  Private
const logout = async (req, res) => {
    // Set token to none and expire after 5 seconds
    res.cookie('token', 'none', {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true,
    })
    res
        .status(200)
        .json({ success: true, message: 'User logged out successfully' })
}

module.exports = {
    login,
    logout,
}
```

Comment: How to do that when the client is offline? Currently working on a PWA with offline mode.

Comment: I can't remove cookie, Because i have two different domains for frontend and server. But i can set token when user logs in.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to do that.

First install js-cookie package

```
npm i js-cookie
```

Then

```
Cookies.remove('name')
```

That is all you need.

If you want to learn more about js-cookie follow this url : https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

And then you can create a hook to handle authentication session. I prefer to use redux to handle states and I store them in a cookie generally or localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting cookie on page load

```
useEffect(() => {
      if(anyCondition){
        document.cookie = '<cookieName>=; Max-Age=0;secure';path=<requiredpath>;
      }
  }, []);
```